# Do you really need to check if MediaPlayer is running before stopping it?

Tags: android

Do I really need to check if my music is playing before calling `mediaplayer.stop();` ? also do I really need to check if my text to speech is speaking before stopping it?

```
if (ttsEngine.isSpeaking()) ttsEngine.stop();
```

This does not always detect if it is working, but if I just call `ttsEngine.stop();` It works fine. so what's the point of checking?

Comment: You're asking two questions and that is generally frowned upon here because it creates confusion.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MediaPlayer Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started,
>   Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped
>   state. Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until
>   prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object
>   to the Prepared state again. Calling stop() has no effect on a
>   MediaPlayer object that is already in the Stopped state.

So I guess You can use `stop()` without checking if MediaPlayer is playing or not